# Access response JSON array from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem. I'm sending file via AJAX (XMLHttpRequest). Anyways. PHP function is returning a response array encoded to JSON. I can catch array in JavaScript but i can't access to specified key in array.

Here is the console log of this array:

`{"data":"cos","data1":"cos1"}`

I have my JavaScript file:

```
$('input[name=zdjecie]').on("change",function() {
    var inputfile = document.querySelector('#file');
    var file = inputfile.files[0];

    $('button[type=submit]').addClass('disabled');

    var formData = new FormData();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
        var pro = Math.round(e.loaded/e.total * 100);
        if(pro == 100) {
            $('#upload_progress').css({'width':pro+'%', background:'#00A65A'});        
            $('button[type=submit]').removeClass('disabled');                
        }
        else {
            $('#upload_progress').css({'width':pro+'%', background:'#3C8DBC'});   
        }
    }, false);        

    formData.append('file', file);
    request.open('post', '/admin/ajax/upload-admin-photo');
    request.send(formData);
    request.onloadend = function() {
        var result = request.response;                
        console.log(result.data);
    };
});
```

Now PHP function that is executing after POST request:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/ajax/upload-admin-photo")
 */
public function ajaxUploadAdminPhotoAction(Request $request)
{ 
    $data = $_FILES;

    $response = array("data" => 'cos', 'data1' => 'cos1');
    return new Response(json_encode($response)); 
}
```

Console log of variable `result`: `{"data":"cos","data1":"cos1"}`

Console log of variable `result.data`: `undefined`

I really need some help. I was trying everything! :(

Comment: you need to parse (=decode) the string `'{"data":"cos","data1":"cos1"}'` to a json first:
 `var result = JSON.parse(request.response);`

Comment: Yes ! That's it. Post answer and I will accept it!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse (=decode) the string `'{"data":"cos","data1":"cos1"}'` to a json first:

```
var result = JSON.parse(request.response);
// now you can access it's params:
console.log(result.data);
```

see [the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for more information.